# Reading Mifare 1k card with Key A and B

Tags: c#, nfc, rfid, mifare

I'm new to reading MIFARE Classic cards and wondering how to access each sector with Key A (`A0A1A2A3A4A5`) and a given Key B (which remains secret).

I have a method setup that loads each key into the reader (OMNIKEY 5421):

- for Key A: keyNo = 20 (`0x14`)
- for Key B: keyNo = 27 (`0x1B`)

Then the keys are authorized in a loop:

```
while (loops > 0)
{
    if (mifareCard.Authenticate(blockAddress, keyTypeA, keyNumberA) == false)
    {
        //throw new Exception("Can't authenticate under key 0 (key type A)");
        //DisplayText("WARNING: authentication under transport key failed. Ending test sequence.");
        Debug.WriteLine("WARNING: authentication under transport key A failed. Ending test sequence.");

        return;
    }

    if (mifareCard.Authenticate(blockAddress, keyTypeB, keyNumberB) == false)
    {
        //throw new Exception("Can't authenticate under key 0 (key type A)");
        //DisplayText("WARNING: authentication under transport key failed. Ending test sequence.");
        Debug.WriteLine("WARNING: authentication under transport key B failed. Ending test sequence.");

        return;
    }

    loops--;
    loopsDone++;
    DisplayText("OK-authenticate(loop #" + loopsDone + ") for access to sector " + sector + ", block " + blockWithinSector);
}
```

- `blockAddress` being the block number
- `keyTypeA` being the type of key. E.g. 96 (`0x60`) for A and 97 (`0x61`) for B
- `keyNumberA` being the slot from the reader

However when Key B gets authorized it returns a SW `69 82` which means
'Access conditions not fulfilled'

Is there a way to authenticate both keys?

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to try to authenticate with both keys after each other. Both authentication attempts will succeed if the keys are correct.

From a practical perspective it's unclear to me why you would want to authenticate with both keys though. In a typical MIFARE Classic application scenario, you would only use one key at each end, e.g.

- Key A to read sectors at less trustful machines in the field <=> Key B to write sectors at trusted machines used for personalization
- Key A for decrementing card balance at POS/vending machines in the field <=> Key B for incrementing card balance at trusted/more secure top-up points

As to why authentication fails in your case is difficult/impossible to tell as we don't know

- how you implemented `mifareCard.Authenticate` and what values you actually provide as parameters (though as you succeed with key A, they are likely correct)
- how you configured your card (Are the access bits set up correctly to allow authentication with key B? Are you using the right value for key B?)

Answer (score -2):

http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S50YYX_V1.pdf
check the access conditions. by default any new rfid mifare classic 1k tag is in transport configuration.
contact the API provider. they will send you the updated DLL including the Method to modify access conditions and to authenticate/modify both the keys. by default key values for both A|B key is "FFFFFFFFFFFF"(12-byte)